# MockBuilder doesn't see method in Interface

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I'm trying to mock Throwable interface but MockBuilder doesn't see getPrevious() method.

```
    $throwableMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\Throwable::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $throwableMock->method('getPrevious')
        ->willReturn($domainExceptionMock);
```

I get this error:

```
Trying to configure method "getPrevious" which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static
```

If i add addMethods to mock builder, like this:

```
$throwableMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\Throwable::class)
        ->addMethods(['getPrevious'])
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
```

I get the following error:

```
Trying to set mock method "getPrevious" with addMethods(), but it exists in class "Throwable". Use onlyMethods() for methods that exist in the class
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`Throwable::getPrevious()` is either final or static so you cannot mock that.

If you create a class with final method and try to mock it you will get the same error message.

```php
class Foo {
  final public function say()
  {

  }
}

$throwableMock = $this->getMockBuilder(Foo::class)
                              ->getMock();

$throwableMock->method('say')
              ->willReturn('xxx');

// Trying to configure method "say" which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static
```

So you should mock the concrete `Exception` class instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the mocked exception, but you may find it easier to build a real object, and then throw that:

```
class SanityTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testThrowingMock(): void
    {
        $domainExceptionMock = new \RuntimeException('hello');
        $exception = new \Exception('msg', 0, $domainExceptionMock);

        $tst = $this->createMock(Hello::class);  // class Hello {public function hello() {} }
        $tst->method('hello')
            ->willThrowException($exception);

        try {
            $tst->hello();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->assertInstanceOf(\RuntimeException::class, $e->getPrevious());
        }
    }
}
```

Mocking everything can be more difficult than setting up & using, and/or checking the real objects after the fact.